# find new function using given function that generates twice the output of given function

Tags: function, probability, probability-theory

Given a function that generates numbers from 1 to 6 with equal probability. Find a function by doing operations on given function such that it produces numbers from 1 to 12 with equal probability.

My approach:
I was maintaining a count variable. If count is an even number then I was adding 0 else I was adding 6 to `f()`. But there are unlimited number of calls to `f()` so, we can't use count variable.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you share source code?

Comment: @Reborn, I have edited my question to include my approach. Please check once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `f6()` be the function that generates values from 1 to 6 with equal probability.
We can call `f6()` twice and store the result in two separate variables `a` and `b`.

Now by using the expression `(a + (b&1)*6)`, we can generate numbers from 1 to 12 with equal probability.

**Explanation:**

`a` and `b` will range from 1 to 6. since `f6()` is generating numbers with equal probability.

`(b&1)` will return either `0` or `1` equally likely depending on whether b is even or odd respectively.

Now, In case `b&1` is `0`, we will have range from 1 to 6 since the `(b&1)*6 = 0`. So, result can only be the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

And in case `b&1` is `1`, result can only be the values 7, 8, 9,10, 11, 12 as `(b&1)*6 = 6`.

Comment: Very simple and easy to understand. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 1):

*f* draws integers from 1 to 6 with equal probability. Now you want to extend this to integers from 1 to 12.
So introduce *g* which draws an integer from 0 to 1 with equal probability.

> *(g \times 6) +  f*
>
> should show the desired behaviour.

Comment: Why is there a downvote. Did i confuse something? I am happy to discuss this.

Comment: The reason that somebody has down voted your answer might be due to the fact that you have deduced a new function `g()` whereas question requires to use the same function `f()`.

Comment: The accepted answer does exactly the same as my proposed answer - the only difference is, it does not call (b&1) a function. whereas you can easily see that you might do so: g(b) = (b&1).

Comment: Also there is the possibility to comment on an answer, do give the OP a Chance to adapt and improve instead of downvoting without giving a hint.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. I don't know who did. And yes, your approach is also correct. Thanks.

Comment: But it wasn't that clear that at first. Only after you explained, I got your point.